# How to define a command that surronds an argument with parenthesis if it contains a comma?

Tags: macros, parsing

I have a very simple command in which one of the arguments can contain commas, in which case the output may not be easily readable since the text in which it is used may contain other commas, making it non-obvious where that notation ends.

Unfortunately I often forgot to surround this argument with parenthesis, hence the confusion.

How can I redefine that command so that all its occurrences produce the good-looking output(i.e. exactly one pair of parenthesis is used *if* it contains commas)?

---

The particular command is:

```
\newcommand{\SubSeq}[3][\empty]{{#2 \upharpoonright #3}^{#1}}
```

And the argument that might contain a comma is `#3`.

---

**Edit:** I don't really care for more complicated situations like `(a,b),c,d`, you can assume that the input either has parenthesis surrounding the whole argument, or it doesn't have any parenthesis.

*However*, I'd agree that in *ideal* solution I'd like to have parenthesis every time that there's a comma outside delimiters in the argument. (And you can definitely assume delimiters are well matched)

---

Thanks to all who contributed answers! I decided to accept Qrrbrbirlbel's answer because is the most simple solution that achieve the functionality I wanted, but I'm **really** grateful to all of you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xstring}
\newcommand{\SubSeq}[3][]{%
  {#2 \upharpoonright
    \IfSubStr{#3}{,}{%
      \IfBeginWith{#3}{(}{%
        \IfEndWith{#3}{)}{#3}{(#3)}%
      }{(#3)}%
    }{#3}}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
$ \SubSeq{a}{b} $              \par
$ \SubSeq{a}{c, d} $           \par
$ \SubSeq{a}{(e, f)} $         \par
$ \SubSeq{a}{(g, h), i} $      \par
$ \SubSeq{a}{((j, k), l)} $    \par
$ \SubSeq{a}{[m, n]} $         \par
$ \SubSeq{a}{(o, p), (q, r)} $ \par
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This produces double-parenthesis when used as `\SubSeq{a}{(b,c)}`, which would ruin the output in the cases where I did remember of this issue.

Comment: @Bakuriu Ah, I didn’t get that that should be caught. What output should `\SubSeq[3]{f}{(g,h), i, k}` give?

Comment: Well, I don't really care because I don't have occurrences of it in my text, but *ideally* I want parenthesis whenever there is a comma not surrounded by parenthesis in the argument.

Comment: I guess no parentheses should be added in the square brackets case...

Comment: @Bakuriu I have updated my answer. Though, you will need some form of intelligent parsing to catch all possible uses of delimiters like the last two examples.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I've already seen and upvoted. I'm going to wait some more time before accepting to allow other people to edit/post their answer.

Comment: @jfbu Sure, but what about `[a, b)`? Or `(o, p), (q, r)`? I’m sure LaTeX3 solutions are more appropriate to catch all possible uses of delimiters and commas.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it seems to me the original justification for adding parentheses basically disappears with things like `(o, p), (q, r)` or `[a, b)`. Added parentheses would be more of a nuissance, and besides should be made larger as delimiters. As for using the full-strength of LaTeX3 ready made tools, why not, but as LaTeX is a mark-up language or supposedly so, at some point the user is in charge of making his source informative, so the parentheses should anyhow in my opinion be added explicitely by the author of the TeX file, rather than given to some complicated ressource wasting macro.

Comment: @jfbu I agree. Sometimes enough is enough. Let the user do a little bit of the work. :)

Answer (score 11):

This avoids adding extra parentheses, also when the material is within square brackets or other delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddParenMaybe}[1]{\@addparen@ #1\@addparen@ }
\def\@addparen@ #1#2\@addparen@ {\in@{#1}{\left([<\{}% add more if necessary
                               \ifin@\expandafter\@thirdofthree
                                    \else\expandafter\@firstofone
                               \fi
                               {\in@{,}{#1#2}%
                                 \ifin@\expandafter\@firstoftwo
                                 \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
                                 \fi}%
                                {(#1#2)}{#1#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
$
 \AddParenMaybe{b} \quad
 \AddParenMaybe{c,d} \quad
 \AddParenMaybe{(c,d)} \quad
 \AddParenMaybe{X^{X^X},d} \quad
 \AddParenMaybe{\left(X^{X^X},d\right)} \quad
$
\end{document}
```

> [image: conditional parentheses]

Answer (score 8):

This may be more or less daunting than Qrrbrbirlbel's answer, depending on the background. `;-)` But checking first for an open parentheses and then for a comma is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\SubSeq}{o m m}
  {
   \bakuriu_subseq:nn {#2}{#3}
   \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bakuriu_subseq:nn #1 #2
 {
  #1 \upharpoonright \nolinebreak
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #2 } { ( } 
   { #2 } % there is ( so we do nothing
   { % there is no (, check if a comma is present
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #2 } { , }
     { (#2) }
     { #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$
 \SubSeq{a}{b} \quad
 \SubSeq{b}{c,d} \quad
 \SubSeq[3]{f}{(g,h)}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The following extension should not be taken too seriously. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\SubSeq}{o m m}
  {
   \bakuriu_subseq:nn {#2}{#3}
   \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bakuriu_subseq:nn #1 #2
 {
  #1 \upharpoonright \nolinebreak
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #2 } { , }
   % there is a comma, so we do a more complicated check
   { \bakuriu_check_parens:n { #2 } }
   % no comma, print the argument as is
   { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bakuriu_check_parens:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A \( .* \) \Z } { #1 }
   % we have parentheses at start and end
   {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A \( .* (\(|\)) .* \) \Z } { #1 }
     % we have parentheses inside, add a pair of braces
     {
      % check for unbalanced parentheses if we remove the first
      \regex_match:nnTF { \A \( (.*?\(.*?\).*).* \) } { #1 }
       { #1 }
       { ( #1 ) }
     }
     % no inner parentheses
     { #1 }
   }
   % no outer parentheses
   { ( #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$
 \SubSeq{a}{b} \quad
 \SubSeq{b}{c,d} \quad
 \SubSeq[3]{f}{(g,h)}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{(b,c)}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{(b,c),d}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{(b,c),(d,e)}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{((b,c),(d,e))}
$

$
\SubSeq[2]{a}{(b,c),d,(e,f)}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{a,(b,c),e}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{(a,(b,c),e)}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{a,(b,(c,d)),e}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{(a,(b,(c,d)),e)}
$
\end{document}
```

One might allow different inner delimiters, by first normalizing them to parentheses with a suitable regex substitution, this is left as an exercise. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: I don’t know if this even makes sense as input and output but what about `\SubSeq[3]{f}{(g,h), i, k}`? I expect there to get `((g, h), i, k)` in the final output.

Comment: egreg, before correcting, you will want to note that his *next* objection will be that your code does not handle `(g,h),(i,k)` as input.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This can be accomplished, with a more complicated parsing. Let's wait for Bakuriu telling something about it.

Comment: @RyanReich ooh I like a challenge:-)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SubSeq}[3][\empty]{{#2 \upharpoonright \sbox0{$\zz#3$}\zzl#3\zzr}^{#1}}
\def\zz{\global\let\zzl\relax\global\let\zzr\relax\count@\z@
\zzdef\({\advance\count@\@ne}%
\zzdef\){\advance\count@\m@ne}%
\zzdef\,{\ifnum\count@=\z@\global\let\zzl(\global\let\zzr)\fi}%
}
\def\zzdef#1{\mathcode`#1"8000\begingroup\lccode`~`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


egreg, before correcting, you will want to note that his next objection will be
that your code does not handle (g,h),(i,k) as input. - Ryan Reich 1 hour ago

$
 \SubSeq{a}{(g,h),(i,k)}
$


$
 \SubSeq{a}{b} \quad
 \SubSeq{b}{c,d} \quad
 \SubSeq[3]{f}{(g,h)}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{(b,c)}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{(b,c),d}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{(b,c),(d,e)}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{((b,c),(d,e))}
$

$
\SubSeq[2]{a}{(b,c),d,(e,f)}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{a,(b,c),e}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{(a,(b,c),e)}
$

$
\SubSeq{a}{a,(b,(c,d)),e}\quad
\SubSeq{a}{(a,(b,(c,d)),e)}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your `\zzdef` macro.  It's very elegant (I mean, aside from the standard cleverness of `\lowercase`).

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to David's doing the hard work, I can give a version of his answer that does not use count registers.  Instead, it just lets TeX count the nesting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\SubSeq[3][\empty]{%                                                                                                                                                                              
  {#2 \upharpoonright \sbox0{$\zz#3\zzg$}\zzp(#3\zzp)}^{#1}%                                                                                                                                                  
}

\def\zzdef#1{%                                                                                                                                                                                                
  \mathcode`#1"8000\begingroup
  \lccode`~`#1%                                                                                                                                                                                               
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}%                                                                                                                                                                                 
}

\def\zz{%                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  \zzdef\,{\let\zzp\relax}%                                                                                                                                                                                   
  \zzdef\({\begingroup}%                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \zzdef\){\endgroup}%                                                                                                                                                                                        
  \let\zzp\@gobble
}

\def\zzg{%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  \global\let\zzp\zzp
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\SubSeq{a}{(g,h),(i,k)}$

$\SubSeq{a}{b} \quad                                                                                                                                                                                          
 \SubSeq{a}{c,d} \quad                                                                                                                                                                                        
 \SubSeq[3]{f}{(g,h)}$

$\SubSeq{a}{(b,c)} \quad                                                                                                                                                                                      
 \SubSeq{a}{(b,c),d}$

$\SubSeq{a}{(b,c),(d,e)} \quad                                                                                                                                                                                
 \SubSeq{a}{((b,c),(d,e))}$

$\SubSeq[2]{a}{(b,c),d,(e,f)}$

$\SubSeq{a}{a,(b,c),e}\quad                                                                                                                                                                                   
 \SubSeq{a}{(a,(b,c),e)}$

$\SubSeq{a}{a,(b,(c,d)),e} \quad                                                                                                                                                                              
 \SubSeq{a}{(a,(b,(c,d)),e)}$
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: In my favor, I dropped it in the first place :)